# Is it possible to make a statusbar like notepad in VB?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, statusbar, statusstrip

I made a notepad using vb 2008 and I am facing a problem who I'd make the Statusbar.

any idea will be great.

Note: I am using the Textbox to read and write text

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to add a `StatusStrip` control to your form.**

To find it, open the Toolbox, expand the "Menus & Toolbars" section, and double-click on the one named "StatusStrip".

Double-clicking on the control in the Toolbox will automatically add it to your form, and dock it along the bottom, just like it is in Notepad.

Once the control is there, you can customize it by changing properties in the Properties window. If you want to add information to the status bar, you do that by adding sub-controls inside of it. Click the drop-down arrow next to the "new" icon, and you'll see a list of possible choices:

- "StatusLabel" — displays static text
- "ProgressBar" — displays a progress bar, indicating the progress of a background operation
- "DropDownButton" — displays a drop-down button, to allow a choice of multiple options
- "SplitButton" — displays a drop-down button that allows a choice of multiple options, but also invokes the default option by a single click on the button.

Comment: first thank you second I add it and add a statusLabel but who to connect it to the Textbox to show me the line number and the position like: "Line 2, Row 6"

Comment: @Bobj-C: You'll have to do that through code. It's not nearly as simple. You should probably ask a new question to get help on that.